# How to pull squashed commit

Tags: git, git-pull

Suppose I have branch, two git clients and git server. Initially all of these have two commits (*a* and *b*):

```
client1:  ...--a--b
client2:  ...--a--b
server:   ...--a--b
```

I have squashed last two commits on *client1* (suppose now it's *c*) and made `git push --force`, so now branch looks like:

```
client1: ...--c
client2: ...--a--b
server:  ...--c
```

Here's the question: how to pull these changes on *client2*? `git pull --force` wants to merge on *client2*, but I just want to pull changes, so that branch on *client2* looks also like:

```
client2: ...--c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fetch then reset at upstream :

```
git fetch
git checkout <appropriate branch>
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

It will make said local branch point at the same commit its remote counterpart does.

As a sidenote, just in case you might regret commits `a` and `b`, you can also make a backup beforehand with

```
git branch <backup-name> <your-current-branch>
```

Comment: Great, that works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking, but a way to get it done would be to delete the project/branch on client 2, and checkout the remote branch/project again.
This also illustrates why you don't want to rewrite history (i.e push force) when commits have already been pushed.

Comment: Yes, now I use this, but deleting branch and checkouting requires longer rebuild.